# External Table from Oracle to SQL 2019

Tags: sql-server, oracle

Im trying to create an external on SQL 2019, the table is located in a Oracle Database. (12C)

First Created the Master Key on SQL DB

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'reallycomplicatePassword@1';
```

Next I created the Oracle DB credential.

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL [OracleCredential]
WITH IDENTITY = 'oracleUserNameHere', SECRET = 'oraclePasswordHere';
```

Next I created the Data Source

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [OracleSalesSrvr]
WITH (LOCATION = 'oracle://myoracleserver',CREDENTIAL = [OracleCredential]);
```

and Finally I try to create the Table

```
  CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE Recharge(

    ORIGINTRANSACTIONID            VARCHAR(20) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN NOT NULL,
    ORIGINOPERATORID               VARCHAR(255) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN NOT NULL

   )
   WITH (
    LOCATION='.SomeOracleSchema.Recharge',
    DATA_SOURCE= OracleSalesSrvr
   );
```

but received the following error :

> Msg 105082, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 105082;Generic ODBC error:
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver]Insufficient information
>   to connect to the data source. Additional error <2>: ErrorMsg:
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver]Insufficient information
>   to connect to the data source., SqlState: HY000, NativeError: 0

My guess i that Im Not specifiying the Services Name or SID while creating the  EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE 
but Im not sure if that is possible or how to do it, (if it is the case).

Comment: I see some posts online about this error with Oracle and other databases too (Progress and DB2 for example) and the one thing they have in common is a mention that the ODBC.INI is not correctly configured. I would locate the ODBC.INI in your Oracle home and review settings such as HostName, PortNumber, ServiceName and make sure they're correct and present (if not present). Ref. https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=479856844300829

Comment: Same issue here, I tried to ask microsoft to document it better...
I tried to play with connection options; but I was not successfull...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found by my dba : 
WITH(
LOCATION='[ServiceName].[SchemaName].[Table]',